# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Tags: numpy

I am getting error while compile this code. Please help

```
train_images = train_images.as_matrix()
train_labels = train_labels.as_matrix()

test_images = test_images.as_matrix()
test_labels = test_labels.as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `np.asmatrix()` as it seems that your array's are numpy array, which haven't got an `as_matrix()` property, as such

```
train_images = np.asmatrix(train_images)
train_labels = np.asmatrix(train_labels)
```

and the same for the test set